# Is it possible to return an HttpResponse in django with text & a json object?

Tags: django, django-views, httpresponse

In my view function, I'd like to return a json object (data1) and some text/html (form). Is this possible?

Here is part of my **views.py**:

```
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
...
    if form.is_valid():
        answer = form.cleaned_data['answer'] # Answer extracted from form is also a string
        a1 = ques1.correct_answer
                    if a1 == answer:
            test1 = question_list.get(id=nextid)
            form = AnswerForm(test1)
            ques1 = question_list.filter(id=nextid)                     # Filter next question as <qs>
            data1 = serializers.serialize("json",ques1)                 # Json-ize
    # ********EDITED HERE **********        
            variables1 = Context({
                'form' : form,
                'q1'   : data1,
            })  
            #response = HttpResponse()
            #response['data1'] = response.write(data1)
            #response['form'] = response.write(form) 
            if nextid <= qsnlen:
                return HttpResponse(variables1, mimetype="application/json")
                #return HttpResponse(response)
            else:
...
```

I'd like to send back both the form html and the ques1 json object. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13):

Use [JsonResponse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
response_data = {put your data into a dict}
return JsonResponse(response_data, status=201)
```

Answer (score 11):

Just put both pieces of data in a JSON container, one key with the form data and one with the HTML as a rendered string. In the browser, you can just pull both keys out & do your thing.

In your view:

```
form_json_data = get_form_json_data()
rendered_html = get_the_html()
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({
        "formdata": form_json, 
        "html": rendered_html}),
    content_type="application/json")
```

In js:

```
$.post(foo, postdata, function(data){
    var formdata = data.formdata
    var html = data.html;
    $(".html-target").replaceWith(html);
    do_whatever(formdata);
})
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested, but the problem is that 'ques1' above is a queryset, and json.dumps complains that is cannot serialize this queryset. In fact, it complains even if you try to serialize just the object ('test1'). Also, in my code above, the two things I'd like to send back are the form and the question object.

Comment: Well yeah, you can't JSON-serialize Python objects. You can't send 'the question object', per se; you can only send a JSON dict of the object's attributes. Django has a [built-in serialization helper](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) that can handle querysets.

Comment: To Import HttpResponse: **from django.http import HttpResponse**

Answer (score 0):

To do this with one response; you need to send the JSON as a plain text in the context of your template response (HTML).

If you need to send JSON as as a separate JSON object, with its own mime type, then you need to write two views; one that sends back the JSON as `application/json` and the other that sends back the form (HTML).

EDIT:

You are not returning JSON objects, but you are turning a dictionary that has two items of two different types. As I explained in the comments, in one request/response cycle; you can only return one response which has a specific mime type that is based on the content and how you want the browser to handle it. Most of the time the content type is `'text/html'`.

In your scenario, if you want to return both the HTML (which is your form), and the JSON response (which is a string), you need to return HTML.

If you want to return JSON to Jquery as a JSON object; you need to detect the request type. In your front end (the templates), you will initiate two requests - one from the browser, which will return back the form. The other from jQuery, which will return the appropriate JSON object.

Here is a possible approach to this:

```
  def foo(request):
     if request.is_ajax():
        ctx = dict()
        ctx['hello'] = 'world'
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(ctx),content_type='application/json')
     else:
        return HttpResponse('hello world')
```

Comment: Just to be 100% clear - I am sending one HttpRequest POST request with form data (via ajax), so I can only route it to one view function. In my scenario, when the user submits an answer to a question, I'd like to take in that data, do things with it, and then send back another question json object and a new input form.

Comment: You can return one response, with multiple objects in the context. This can be of only one _mime type_ - so you can send multiple items in a response back; but you *cannot* combine two mime types in one response.

In your example you are setting the mimetype as `application/json`. You can technically send anything you want and put the mimetype as whatever, but this won't do what you want on the client end.

To send the HTML for the form and the JSON object - add the JSON object to the context of the response.

Comment: Please check the edited code above. I added both the form and the json object to the context, and I am sending that back. Is this what you mean? Will the json object read correctly on the client side (I am using jquery)? Reading this on the client side will be a bit of a nightmare, I think. I didn't use RequestContext since there are many more variables that are returned back that I do not need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot have two return statements; only the first one will work. With one request - you can only have one response returned. You cannot fork two responses, with two different mime types, in one request/response cycle.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant to comment out the second return statement. Although I now get both form and json object in the response, I am still trying to figure out how to un-package it appropriately on the client side via jquery.